# How can I make a cell movable but not deletable in a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

#### My aim

Hello, my problem is quite simple. I have a `UITableView` with a couple of cells. Some of them can be deleted (but not necessarily all of them), but all of them can be movable.

#### My problem

I do not understand how to realize this through the iOS SDK. Using a combination of `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` I am only able to set a cell as deletable, and eventually movable, but not vice versa. I would like to set a cell as movable but **not necessarily** deletable. Is this possible?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Movable:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath         
{
    return YES;
}
```

### Non-Deletable:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Comment: I thought I could do it from the delegate itself. Did not see that method in the delegate ... I had to change the core code of my app, but now it works, thank you!

Comment: Add this as well - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}