# How to add an image in UITableView's content view while we reodering cells?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a tableview where I provide the option to reoder the cells. But, I don't want to show the delete icon when the user doing rearranging cells. So I did like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116618/how-can-i-make-a-cell-movable-but-not-deletable-in-a-uitableview) to remove the delete button.

In normal mode..

[image]

After edit mode (That is, non deletable but rearrangable mode)..

[image]

Here, two things are happening. One is the accessoryview of each cell has a image(that represents rearrangement). Second thing is, all strings are moved some points from the left screen. This gap is actually for the deletion symbol. Since I hide the delete button, an empty space appears.

Ok, here is the problem comes. I now want to add some custom button with an image in each cell's content view.

So, I added the following code in my `tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
if (isEditable)
{
    selectionButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_button.png"];

    selectionButton.frame = CGRectMake(-25, 10, img.size.width, img.size.height);

    [selectionButton setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [selectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClickAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:selectionButton];
}
```

The blue button was 24*24 pixels.

**The reason why I used -25 as "x" value:**

If I give a positive value or zero, the button will overlapped with cell text. Below image represents when the x value is 0.

[image]

But for x=-25,

[image]

**What I need:**

Since I added the button with negative x value, the whole image width (24 pixels) will be hiden in the x value (25 pixels). So the button action `buttonClickAction:` was not called. I want to change the image when the user tapping on it(switching between selected/unselected mode).

Is there any way to call the button's action method? Or should I create a custom cell?

Just confused..

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Table View Controller

```
- (BOOL) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldIndentWhileEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
            return NO;
}
```

It will remove empty space.